# Can we use camera2 API to access Canon DSLR camera

Tags: android, android-camera2

I would like to take a picture from `DSLR` camera by using android device. Is it possible that I can use `camera2` API for this?

Comment: Could you show what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Android **camera2** API supports [USB webcams](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/external-usb-cameras) if the V4L drivers match. Even for these, bandwidth is often the bottleneck, because I have not yet seen Android OTG (USB Host-mode) with USB3 performance. USB2 is not capable of passing full HD video at 30FPS.

Worse with DSLR camera. Even if it has V4L-compliant USB interface, it is probably tuned for the highest edge, not the mediocre USB2 capabilities of Android hosts.

Answer (score 0):

While several dSLR cameras do have remote-control APIs that work over USB (here's [Canon's](https://www.developersupport.canon.com/content/canon-digital-camera-software-developers-kit-general-information)), as far as I know they are all proprietary, and don't expose a standard UVC (USB video class) interface.

So while it may be possible to write an Android app that talks to a Canon dSLR, it can't be done via camera2.  You'd have to use the Android USB APIs directly, and probably reverse-engineer the Canon SDK, which is only available on Windows and Mac, for the USB protocol.